Displaying a move in chess in LaTeX

I decided to try to design chess solutions and ran into a little difficulty. I wanted the move display (the white square in the photo) to be a circle or triangle instead of a square. I have already seen in some chess books that this is done. How to realize this in LaTeX?
\begin{center}
\fenboard{2rqr1k1/pb1nbp2/1p3npp/2pp4/3P4/2NBPPN1/PP3BPP/1Q2RRK1 w - - 0 1}
\chessboard[showmover=true]
\end{center}


can you complete your snippet so we can reproduce the output you show? this does not seem to have much to do with the engine. what makes you think it only applies to pdftex?

Use moverstyle in the chessboard parameters. In addition to circle and triangle, there is a squarearrow option. Here is an example with the circle and triangle:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{skak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\fenboard{2rqr1k1/pb1nbp2/1p3npp/2pp4/3P4/2NBPPN1/PP3BPP/1Q2RRK1 w - - 0 1}
\chessboard[moverstyle=circle,showmover=true]
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\fenboard{2rqr1k1/pb1nbp2/1p3npp/2pp4/3P4/2NBPPN1/PP3BPP/1Q2RRK1 w - - 0 1}
\chessboard[moverstyle=triangle,showmover=true]
\end{center}

\end{document}


You can also define your own using:
\cbDefineMoverStyle[〈commands〉]{〈name of style〉}{〈white top〉} {〈white bottom〉}{〈black top〉}{〈black bottom〉}

In the last four parameters (〈white top〉 etc) you define the mover symbol for those four cases.
